# Marshal.PtrToStructure on Android return null

Tags: c#, android, c++, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game project using unity3d.
Now I'm trying pass Structure from c++ to C# in unity.
Structure in c++ like below:

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
class BuildData  
{  
public:
  int m_ID;   
  int m_BuildType;   
  int m_NameID;  
  int m_DescriptionID;  
  int m_BuildLV; 
  int m_Group;    
  unsigned char m_OpenFlag;   
  unsigned char m_ShowFlag;  
  float m_UIDisplaySize;    
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

In unity3d c# project, I declare the structure like that.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct BuildData
{
  public int m_ID;                  
  public int m_BuildType;           
  public int m_NameID;              
  public int m_DescriptionID;       
  public int m_BuildLV;             
  public int m_Group;         
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]     
  public bool m_OpenFlag;    
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]         
  public bool m_ShowFlag; 
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]  
  public float m_UIDisplaySize;     
};
```

And I using the code below to get data.

```
System.IntPtr ptr = MethodToGetIntPtr();   
BuildData convert_data = (BuildData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(BuildData));
```

It works good on pc and android x86, but on android armeabi,  it fails.
I get an IntPtr that not equal IntPtr.zero but Marshal.PtrToStructure will return null.

I have no idea why have this result.
Have someone can answer it?

Comment: thanks your quick reply, you are right.
After your answer,  I add two fields to the structure and get the same result (return null). 
I updated my question.

Comment: I think you should not update your question here based on answer otherwise ppl referring in future would get confused about problem you asked.

Comment: I will post a new question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent of `unsigned char` in `C#` is `System.Byte`.
Changing you datatype in `C#` will solve your problem.
You can check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wf2yk2k.aspx) for more details.